# Why is a wordpress theme stylesheet taking one minute to load?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, loading

I'm helping a friend with their site at http://www.connecttoyourangels.co.uk/ and since a recent update of wordpress and various plugins the site is taking over a minute to load.

Chrome network tab shows the culprit is the theme stylesheet at  http://www.connecttoyourangels.co.uk/wp-content/themes/clifden/assets/css/style.css.php?ver=20130124 but I've got no idea why the stylesheet is taking so long to load as its no larger than many other files on the page.

Any ideas how I can debug further to find out why it's so slow to load?

Comment: Why is the stylesheet a PHP file? THAT is the reason, FYI - if you look, all the static assets load quickly, but that PHP file takes a long time.  Something's not right with that file, or with the way PHP is being processed on that server.

Comment: FYI, my previous comment is further supported by the very long load time of this file as well: http://www.connecttoyourangels.co.uk/wp-content/themes/clifden/assets/js/nivo/apply-nivo.js.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very narrowly focused and will likely not help future visitors.

Comment: Looking at the php file there are a tonne of @readfile's inside which I guess is what is taking so long and gives me my answer, thanks

Comment: any cache plugin or cloudflare will help to resolve this.

Comment: @Gazi - IMO that's a band-aid to cover poor design / architecture.

Comment: @cale_b agreed, i've got W3 cache setup but the issue is the awful coding in that file, commented them out and reloaded as a test and sure enough the page loads fine with those readfile's out.

Comment: you are right years ago I was doing the same mistake and it was loading to much when you use css in php file.However the best way to use php in style is to get styles in header.php instead